# Firestore feed/timeline modeling

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make feed/timeline where a user can follow - Category,Album or another User. Every time a picture is added to Category,Album,User it should appear on the timeline. I am trying to model my database so it requires 1-2 get requests only.

- One idea for the solution is fan-out structure, But how do i make the multi-path update in Firestore? How can i update all the followers timelines when someone uploads a photo ?
- How do i structure the database when i cant query on sub-collections? Should i just make one collection which contains all user timeline posts as separate documents, which will be ridiculous amount of duplicated data.
- Is there any other way instead of fan-out to structure a user timeline ?

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I make the multi-path update in Firestore?

The equivalent of Firebase Realtime Database's multi-path updates, are called batched writes in Cloud Firestore. You can read more in the [documentation on batches writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: Batch writes have 500 document limit. So if an album has 1 mil followers i need to make 2k batch writes, and every batch write is still the same price as 500 writes. So for every new pictures i will be still paying for 1 mil writes.

Comment: Yes, both your statements are correct. But batch writes are still the way to do these updates.

Answer (score 0):

Flat.

```
root
  pictures
    uid-abc123
      url:"http://test.com/img1.jpg"
      owner:useriduid,
      created: 1529333679449
    uid-abc1billion
      url:"http://test.com/img1billion.jpg"
      owner:useriduid,
      created: 1529333679300
```

Querying and security rules are then easy as pie. You can add [indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) and it's very scalable.

Re multipath writes, use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that code has nothing to do with my question. The problem is structuring the timeline so i can make few requests to get it for a certain user. So i need to get the categories,albums that a user likes, and then get the pictures added to those in the last 24 hours , then when user scrolls on page 2 get the pictures from 24 to 48 hours and so on.

Comment: Your pictures should have a `created:unix-timestamp` property that you can `.where("created", "<", unix-timestamp)` query on. ...I added the `created` property to my answer to help visualize that.